# Visual Studio 2017 not discovering NUnit tests when tests class inherits from a class that implements NHibernate

Tags: c#, spring, visual-studio, nhibernate, nunit-3.0

I'm having this issue that can't resolve, I'm upgrading from NUnit 2.6.4 to 3.9.0, my test project have multiple test class, and when I change NUnit version, some of my tests weren't discovered by test explorer, after some research, all tests missing inherits or somehow implement NHibernate and Spring NUnit testing nuget package. When I remove inheritance, tests are discover. No solution works for this.

> Nuget packages version: 
>   Spring.Testing.NUnit 
>   2.0.1 NUnit 3.9.0
>   NHibernate 3.3.3.4
>   NUnitTestAdapter 3.9

This is my NHibernate class:

```
using System;
using NHibernate;
using Spring.Data.NHibernate.Generic;
using Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support;
using Spring.Testing.NUnit;

namespace Testproject{
    public class NHibernateTestClass : AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests
    {
    //Some methods here
    }


}
```

This is my test class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Testproject{
    public class TestClass: NhibernateTestClass{
        //Some test methods here
    }
}
```

I have tried referencing NUnit framework in my NHibernateTestClass but, with no result.

**Edit:**

Forgot to add that my Hibernate test class was inheriting from that spring test class.

Answer (score 0):

Just install NUnit3TestAdapter via nuget.

And add NUnit attributes([TestFixture],[Test]) before class and method declaring.

Comment: I already have it installed, there are over 3000 tests, but only ones that inherits from NHibernateTestClass aren't being discovered.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: Maybe you need to add some NUnit attributes(like [TestFixture] and [Test]) before class and method declaring

Comment: I already tried that, again no result. This issue is blowing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have simmilar problem but with visual studio 2015 (community)

I have 2 test classes one is:

```
namespace WarehouseTemplate.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test1  
    {


        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {

        }

        [Test()]
        public void Can_generate_schema()
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();

            cfg.Configure();

            new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false);

        }
    }
}
```

With can be found in test explorer, and then i have this one

```
namespace WarehouseTemplate.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestDao : AbstractDaoIntegrationTests
    {
        private IProductDao productDao;

        private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        // These properties will be injected based on type
        public IProductDao ProductDao
        {
            set { productDao = value; }
        }
        public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            set { sessionFactory = value; }
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
        }

        [Test()]
        public void CustomerDaoTests()
        {//logic here

        }
    }
}
```

where AbstractDaoIntegrationTests looks

```
namespace WarehouseTemplate.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class AbstractDaoIntegrationTests : AbstractTransactionalDbProviderSpringContextTests
    {
        protected override string[] ConfigLocations
        {
            get
            {
                return new string[]
                    {
                        "referenceString"
                    };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i cant find this test only first one:

NUnit Adapter 3.9.0.0: Test execution started
Running all tests in E:\Zabava\C# programy\WarehouseTemplate\WarehouseTemplate\bin\Debug\WarehouseTemplate.exe
NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1 NUnit test cases
NUnit Adapter 3.9.0.0: Test execution complete

So far any tip for possible problem is that spring NET has different NUNIT version which needs scpeficy reference or NUnit Adapter

Comment: As far as we have been doing deep research, spring.test.nunit, haven't been update since 2015, so is pretty much possible that there is a incompatibility issue, we are working in a workaround, avoiding nunit test classes iheriting from spring have make all test to be discovered, now we have the issue to rewrite our transactions cause of this.

Comment: i was thinking maybe "udpate" NUNIT to same version as spring net and then use older Adapter could work. Or as you say, do your own transaction and injects etc what you need

Answer (score 0):

I found Answer and solution
I just instale NUnit 2.6.3 )i manually choose older one, and propriet Adapter version now i can see my tests

[image]

Comment: You dwngrade again to 2.6.4? In our case, we want to upgrade, that's why we are looking for a proper solution instead of a workaround.